# How to add onChange event to dropdown boxes of JQuery.DatePicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have the following situation: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ff6Ex/)

What I want, is to add an `onChange` event to the dropdown boxes of the `datepicker` so that I will be able to capture the selected month/year in the text box above as a new value is selected from the calendar.

PS: Inspecting the relevant dropdown boxes, there is already an `onChange` command assigned that looks like

```
onchange="DP_jQuery_1353406309923.datepicker._selectMonthYear('#datepicker', this, 'M');"
```

I don't want to overwrite this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't approve [suggested edits like this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/823123). If needed, refer to this [meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157423/165773) for details.

Comment: @gnat what are you talking about?

Comment: some of your reviews of suggested edits were complained about in this post at Meta Stack Overflow: **[Users blindly approving suggested edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151947/165773)** "Recently I've noticed quite a few users blindly approving all suggested edits and that's getting somewhat annoying. For example user [MaVRoSCy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1387157/mavroscy)..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`onChangeMonthYear`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onChangeMonthYear) option:

> **onChangeMonthYear**
>
> > Called when the datepicker moves to a new month and/or year. The function receives the selected year, month (1-12), and the datepicker instance as parameters. this refers to the associated input field.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      dateFormat: 'MM yy',
      altField: "#id",
      altFormat: "mm/yy",
      onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, oDatepicker) {
        alert('Year: ' + year + ', Month: ' + month);
      }
    });
});​
```

Your fiddle, updated: http://jsfiddle.net/ff6Ex/1/

Comment: Happens to the best of us! Glad to help :)