# Jquery datepicker remove onclick and onchange and add default attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

When I try to create jquery-datepicker(with month and year menu) and inspect month/year menu using firebug or chrome developer tool I am getting following

```
<select class="ui-datepicker-year"
     onclick="DP_jQuery_1378903097959.datepicker._clickMonthYear('#dp1378903097961');" 
     onchange="DP_jQuery_1378903097959.datepicker._selectMonthYear('#dp1378903097961', this,                'Y');
">
```

Normally when we create jquery-datepicker data should be

```
<select data-event="change" data-handler="selectYear" class="ui-datepicker-year">
```

So, problem is that those additional "`onChange`" and "`onclick`" are causing weird behavior for month and year dropdown

I tried to debug whole jquery creation of datepicker but find my self unable to understand how those attributes are getting added
Can anybody please guide me how I can remove those and add default things like `data-event` and `data-handler` ?

also I found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471386/how-to-add-onchange-event-to-dropdown-boxes-of-jquery-datepicker), but I don't want to add `onChange` event

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an old question but not answered. I had the same problem and used the solution [here](http://www.serkey.com/jquery-r2592-datepicker-removed-inline-onclick-and-onchange-attributes-from-month-year-dropdowns-tod-bbthv3.html)

It worked all right for me. Hope it helps.

Also I think this is tracked as a [bug](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6198)

But not clear which version has the fix.